# Run Python script on EC2 instance via SSM

Tags: aws-ssm

I can run shell commands on an EC2 instance via SSM [SendCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_SendCommand.html) w/ `AWS-RunShellScript` document. The same can be done for PowerShell scripts w/ `AWS-RunPowerShellScript`.

There is `AWS-RunRemoteScript` which can run Python script from [S3 or GitHub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/integration-github-python.html), but I don't see anything like `AWS-RunPythonScript` that can run embedded Python script.

Does this simply not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it simply does not exist.

AWS SSM has a fairly straightforward structure - at the very bottom there are finite and quite small number of operations, which documents can run - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/documents-schemas-features.html

Notice that AWS-RunRemoteScript essentially just run `aws:downloadContent`
and then `aws:runPowerShellScript` `aws:runShellScript` which are also used by `AWS-RunShellScript` and `AWS-RunPowerShellScript`.